# Count how many entries that are found that exist before and after a given date

Tags: mysql

Given I have a simple table with 'name' and 'date' fields, is there a way to count how many entries exist, in which the same name field is used at least once before and at least once after a given date.

For instance, given

```
[ name | date ]
Joe, 1/1
Billy, 1/1
Sam, 1/2
James, 1/3
Billy, 1/3
```

Is there a way to ask: "who has been there before 1/2 and also after 1/2"

Given the above table, such a search would result with Billy, because Billy has an entry before 1/2 (on 1/1) and also after 1/2 (on 1/3).

Please do keep in mind that each 'entry' in the database only has a single date field. (and forgive me if I am using the wrong terms for this)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following query should answer the question "Who has been there before 1/2 and also after 1/2?":

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.name
FROM TABLE AS T1, TABLE AS T2
WHERE T1.date < 1/2 AND T2.date > 1/2 AND T1.name = T2.name
```

"TABLE" should be the name of your table. Please make sure to format the dates, we are comparing to, correctly. 
Based on the query above you should be able to count the number of rows - just use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.name)
```

instead. Please note that I have assumed that names are unique, such that there doesn't exist 2 persons in the table with the same name.